# Depend on dynamically generated gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, swagger

I have a multi-module gradle project that looks something like the following

```
books
  books-api
  books-server
  books-tests
  books-client   // generated using 'gradle swagger'
```

The `books-api` contains service.swagger.json file that I'd like to use to generate a Java based client using Swagger codegen gradle plugin. The `books-test` module is a test suite that will use the generated client to run tests agains the server.

The Swagger codegen gradle plugin creates an entire gradle module `books-client`. Currently, the module is generated by running the `swagger` task on the root project. I have to perform this step manually before running a `gradle build` on the root project so that the `books-test` modules dependency on `books-client` is satisfied.

Is there anyway to generate `books-client` and have `books-test` depend on it for just running `gradle build` on the root project? I.e. `gradle build` would generate `books-client` and build `books-test` successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you create the whole gradle module dynamically? Or do you mean you just create the source of the module dynamically?

I'd suggest that you do not create the gradle module dynamically, but have it there with all the necessary dependencies and just let the swagger plugin generate the code. As far as I see in the plugin, the swagger task comes before compileJava anyway.

So my suggested workflow would be that you have the gradle module there and then use the standard gradle build workflow. Or are you running into problems with this approach?

Comment: Changing the API should create a new client. We don't want the client code to become stale because it requires a manual step. Everything should just work when someone checks out the repo and builds it.

Comment: I got that (and it makes sense of course). What I do not get is why you need to create the whole module and not just the client that needs to be generated. Or are you doing this already, and I misunderstood your question? Because I have a similar project, but I'm creating the API code from a swagger spec, and this works without problems in the build process.

Comment: It doesn't quite seem to work flawlessly for me. If I don't generate supportingFiles, the generated source seems to be missing some Java files. If I do generate supportingFiles, it will generate the entire gradle module. I don't want to spend time tweaking the generated source, so using the generated gradle module seems the best option.